# Form masked input gets cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, maskedinput

I'm trying to use maskedinput (https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) in a React component which contains different inputs.

The problem is that when I submit the form the masked input gets cleared, and cannot avoid it (and its annoying when the form have errors and the form remains, but with the masked input empty).

I suppose this issue is about React lifecycle but not sure how to solve it.

```
componentDidMount () {
  $("input[name=contact_phone]").mask("(999) 999 9999", {placeholder:"x"});
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If the issue occurs during submission, it would be helpful to see the section of your code that handles that...

Comment: No, that's the problem, I've done lots of debugging on this, and the input clearing occurs before submission (and is problematic specially when there's no real submission because form validation errors), and there is not another render executed either. Is like the masked input not being a real value of the input (but accesible by $element.val() ).

Comment: Well whatever is causing the problem isn't shown in the snippets you've shown.  Hard to debug something without seeing it.